# SharePoint Online Connected Web parts - Prevent Page Refresh

Tags: sharepoint-online, connected-web-parts

I have two connected web parts on a page in SharePoint Online. The first webpart is filtering based on a Querystring parameter and when it is clicked filters the second web part.

The problem I have is when a list item in the first web part is selected, the page refreshes and the Querystring parameter disappears. This means that while the second web part now displays the correct list items as per the connection, the first web part is no longer filtered and displays all records.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for updating the second web part without a page refresh so that the web address still retains the querystring parameter? I worked out how to do it a couple of years ago but just can't find the solution now.

Thanks.